# ring / circular Buffer - buffer implementation and printing values between head and tail

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm a little stucked in my task with circular buffer. I wrote functions push and pop for my ring buffer how it's suppose to work and it seems it works. But when I implement dataBuffer by every element using pushBack and the same in cycle "for" I get different values of head. It can be seen in my example (I can use only 4 values in the structure + the 5th is added for to count number of elements between head and tail):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct ringBuffer
    {
        int *bufferData;
        int head;
        int tail;
        int size;
        int num;
    };

    void bufferFree(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
    {
        free(buffer->bufferData);
    }

    void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int size)
    {
        buffer->size = size;
        buffer->head = 0;
        buffer->tail = 0;
        buffer->bufferData = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    }

    int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int data)
    {
        buffer->bufferData[buffer->tail++] = data;
        if (buffer->tail == buffer->size)
        {
            buffer->tail = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
    {
        if (buffer->head != buffer->tail)
        {
            buffer->head++;
            if (buffer->head == buffer->size)
            {
                buffer->head = 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int bufferSize(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
    {
        //int numElements;
        //numElements = (buffer->size + buffer->head + buffer->tail) % buffer->size; // 8 + 0 + 6 % 8 = 6; 
        if (buffer->head >= buffer->tail)
        {
            return (buffer->head - buffer->tail);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((buffer->size - buffer->tail) + buffer->head);
        }

        /*if (buffer->head = !buffer->tail)
        {
        for (buffer->head = 0; buffer->head < buffer->tail; buffer->head++)
        {
        printf("head[%d] and tail[%d] --> bufferData = %d", buffer->head, buffer->tail, buffer->bufferData);
        }
        }*/
        return 0;
    }

    int printBuffer(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
    {
        int size = bufferSize((ringBuffer*)buffer->size);
        int i = buffer->head;
        while (buffer->size >= 0) 
        {
            if (!buffer->bufferData)
            {
                printf("Buffer is empty\n");
                return -1;
            }
            else if (i == buffer->size)
            {

        i = 0;
            }
            printf("    \n");
            buffer->size--;
        }
        /*printf("Values from HEAD to TAIL: ");
        if (buffer->head == buffer->tail)
        {
            printf("Head and tail are equals, not possible to show data\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bufferData[%d] = %d\n", buffer->bufferData);
        }*/
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        struct ringBuffer buffer;
        int size = 8;
        int data[] = { 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 }; // 20 values
        int dataSize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
        bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);

        printf("1st implementation\n");
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        //printf("Current num elements = \n", bufferSize((ringBuffer*)buffer.num));

        printf("2nd implementation\n");
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        bufferFree(&buffer);

        printf("\nInisialization\n");
        bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
        printf("head = %d, tail = %d - then implementation\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        {
            pushBack(&buffer, data[i]);
            printf("head = %d, tail = %d, dataBuffer = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail, data[i]);
            popFront(&buffer);
        }
        printf("\nbufferData check:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d] = %d  ", i, buffer.bufferData[i]);
        }
        printf("\nhead = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);

        bufferFree(&buffer);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I also have to write a function which shows number of elements between "head" and "tail". For the for cycle there is always 1 value between head and tail, in the first implementation head is always = 0 (and when all the buffer is implemented, head = tail). Here the name is bufferSize. And I have to print that.

How to fix this problem with head and tail and how to write a correct printBuffer function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously happening because your first and second implementation doesn't use `popFront(...)` function that you use in `for` cycle. `popFront(...)` is moving your head forward and obvious that if you push and than pop data in the same cycle only you'll never get more than 1 record in your buffer.

Comment: Anyway it's not the right way. During the first inmplementation the buffer is empty so implementation should be started from head = 0 till tail =7 (the end of the buffer in my case when size is 8 bytes) and only in the second circle head should be moved. Or I don't get something.

Comment: What circle? Please give an example of your program output and show there what in your opinion is wrong.

Comment: Here is the result of output. I put popFront in the second test implementation before the cycle
https://ibb.co/k7AGtv

Comment: So what's the problem? I compiled your program and it does perfectly what it should. Btw, there is no head shift in second implementation(copied code from your fist post). I compiled your program with visual studio 2015 C++ compiler. I only had to change allocation part, but it should not change program's behavior.

Comment: Well, it seems I didn't completely understand and sure how it should work.I was confused (2nd implementation) because of tail value.

Now I changed the part with cycle implementation and devided it by 3 parts: dataSize = 20 so for the 1st it's from  to 5, for the 2nd - from 5 till 13 and for the 3rd from 13 to <dataBuffer. It seems it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish my message here and can't answer anymore. I posted a comment with the code. Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I didn't completely understand and sure how it should work.I was confused (2nd implementation) because of tail value.

Now I changed the part with cycle implementation and devided it by 3 parts: dataSize = 20 so for the 1st it's from  to 5, for the 2nd - from 5 till 13 and for the 3rd from 13 to bufferData in return).

Sorry for such stupid questions but I really wanna learn and understand.

Here is my corrected code and the result of compilation.
https://ibb.co/e6jnGF

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ringBuffer
{
    int *bufferData;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
};

void bufferFree(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    free(buffer->bufferData);
}

void bufferInitialization(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int size)
{
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->head = 0;
    buffer->tail = 0;
    buffer->bufferData = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}

int pushBack(struct ringBuffer *buffer, int data)
{
    buffer->bufferData[buffer->tail++] = data;
    if (buffer->tail == buffer->size)
    {
        buffer->tail = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int popFront(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    if (buffer->head != buffer->tail)
    {
        buffer->head++;
        if (buffer->head == buffer->size)
        {
            buffer->head = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int bufferSize(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    if (buffer->head >= buffer->tail)
    {
        return (buffer->head - buffer->tail);
    }
    else
    {
        return buffer->size - ((buffer->size - buffer->tail) + buffer->head);
    }
    for (buffer->head = 0; buffer->head < buffer->tail; buffer->head++)
    {
        printf("head[%d] and tail[%d] --> bufferData = %d", buffer->head, buffer->tail, buffer->bufferData);
    }
    return 0;
}

int printBuffer(struct ringBuffer *buffer)
{
    for (int i = buffer->head; i < buffer->tail; i++)
    {
        if (buffer->head == buffer->tail)
        {
            printf("Head and tail are equals, not possible to show data\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bufferData = %d\n", buffer->bufferData);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct ringBuffer buffer;
    int size = 8;
    int data[] = { 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 }; // 20 values
    int dataSize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

    bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
    printf("1st implementation\n");
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail); popFront(&buffer);
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));

    printf("2nd implementation\n");
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    pushBack(&buffer, 10);  printf("head = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));
    bufferFree(&buffer);

    printf("\nInisialization\n");
    bufferInitialization(&buffer, size);
    printf("head = %d, tail = %d - then implementation\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        pushBack(&buffer, data[i]);
        printf("head = %d, tail = %d, dataBuffer = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail, data[i]);
    }
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));
    popFront(&buffer);
    printBuffer(&buffer);
    printBuffer((ringBuffer*)buffer.bufferData);

    for (int i = 5; i < 13; i++)
    {
        pushBack(&buffer, data[i]);
        printf("head = %d, tail = %d, dataBuffer = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail, data[i]);
    }
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));
    popFront(&buffer);
    printBuffer(&buffer);
    printBuffer((ringBuffer*)buffer.bufferData);

    for (int i = 13; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        pushBack(&buffer, data[i]);
        printf("head = %d, tail = %d, dataBuffer = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail, data[i]);
    }
    printf("bufferSize = %d\n", bufferSize(&buffer));
    popFront(&buffer);
    printBuffer(&buffer);
    printBuffer((ringBuffer*)buffer.bufferData);



    /* bufferData check */
    printf("\nbufferData check:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] = %d  ", i, buffer.bufferData[i]);
    }
    printf("\nhead = %d, tail = %d\n", buffer.head, buffer.tail);
    bufferFree(&buffer);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could somebody give a comment, please? I still haven't solved it.
@nopasara